# ERROR - Exception occurred during processing request: null java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, struts2, struts

I am trying to create a basic select data in mysql in Struts2 in eclipse. I am getting exceptions that I am unable to solve, the Exception occurred during processing request: null ,my classmate tell me that i probably write wrong struts,but my find's struts copy the insertStudentGrade and the Insert don't wrong,i have no idea...

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="struts2" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="login" class="com.Action.LoginAction">
           <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
           <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="save" class="com.Action.AddStudentGrade" method="insert">
                <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
            </action>
         <action name="find" class="com.Action.FindStudentGrade" method="find">
                <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
            </action>
    </package>

    <include file="example.xml"/>

    <!-- Add packages here -->

</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts Blank</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

problem details

```
08:49:40.900 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler - Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Action.FindStudentGrade.find(FindStudentGrade.java:28) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:897) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1299) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1375) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434) ~[ognl-3.0.21.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:398) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:450) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:396) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:430) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:290) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) ~[xwork-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) ~[struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:575) [struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81) [struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.36.jar:2.3.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_192]
```

the selectStudentGrade

```
package com.Action;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.util.DBUtil;

public class FindStudentGrade extends ActionSupport{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private String stu_id="1";
    public String find() throws SQLException{
        String sql="SELECT stu_id,stu_name,stu_math,stu_chinese,stu_english FROM stu_grade where id='"+stu_id+"'";

        DBUtil dbUtil=new DBUtil();

        ResultSet rSet=dbUtil.executeQuery(sql);
        String id=null;
        String name=null;
        String math=null;
        String chinese=null;
        String english=null;
        while(rSet.next()){
            System.out.println("zxzx");//a test,but can not print in console
            id=rSet.getString("stu_id");
            name=rSet.getString("stu_name");
            math=rSet.getString("stu_math");
            chinese=rSet.getString("stu_chinese");
            english=rSet.getString("stu_english");
        }
        System.out.println(id+name+math+chinese+english);
            return "success";

    }
    }
```

Comment: The Exception Error points to line 28 of `FindStudentGrade.java:28` looks like line: `name=rSet.getString("stu_name");` gets `null`. Inspect the contents of line 19: `ResultSet rSet` and see if all fields contain 
 values. Also, before line 28, maybe try printing out the value of each result, e.g. print `id`, see if you get an error, if not then print `name` until the Exception occurs.

Comment: The exception message says that the error occurred on line 28 as @davedwards said. I don't see how that line `name=rSet.getString("stu_name");` could be throwing a `NullPointerException`. `ResultSet.getString()` should return a `null` if there was a `NULL` in the database. Are you sure the code that you posted is the same code that produced the stack trace?

Comment: Check to make sure that you have some rows in `rSet`.  I suspect that you don't, and that `rSet.next()` immediately returns false.  Thus, you never enter the while loop.

Comment: Don't delete a question when it's answered.